# Как создать контекстное меню из xml файла

Tags: android, android-ui

Сосбтвенно есть задача, реализовать в RecyclerView контекстное меню реагирующие на долгий тап на item. Как сделать его программно - примеров много и они работают. А вот как его реализовать из xml файла я чего то найти не могу....

Comment: Про какое меню идет речь? Которое по долгому тапу на айтеме или какое

Comment: @pavlofff на айтеме

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В слушателе айтема (думаю, знаете как его прописать)

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, view);
popup.inflate(R.menu.options_menu);
popup.show();
```

В чем проблема?